# Add style to border (parent element) when checkbox is selected WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to add differences style to the border when the radio button is checked and not checked. Is there anyway to do this in xaml with binding?

```
<Border
 Width="672"
 Height="122"
 HorizontalAlignment="Left">
 <RadioButton
  Margin="0,0,0,8"
  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
  VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Border>
```

This is what i'm doing now but it doesnt work for me yet

```
<Border.Style>
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
  <Style.Triggers>
   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Child.Children[0].IsChecked}" Value="true">
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="red" />
   </DataTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
</Border.Style>
```

Comment: Yes, have a loot at [triggers](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/styles/trigger-datatrigger-event-trigger/)

Comment: @McNets Can you help me out pls, i'm in a hurry and i quite new to wpf.

Comment: The DataTrigger example fits, it uses a checkbox instead of a radiobutton but, same properties

Comment: <Border.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Child.Children[0].IsChecked}" Value="true">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="red" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Border.Style>

Comment: @McNets This is what i'm doing now but it doesnt work for me yet

Comment: I think you can use IValueConvert

Comment: First, there is no `Children` property in `RadioBotton`. So Path is wrong. Second, binding by nested properties throungh `Background.Child` does not work. Try another way of binding.